# how to check logon account has logon permission to start service + c#

Tags: c#

I am having 3 useraccounts locally: Admin/Administrator/AdminUser. Manually i can check whether the specific account has "logon to start service" permission. My question is how to check it programatically.

Using WMI-win32_useraccounts i am able to verify the accounts are available or not.

Can anyone provide some light on how to search specific account has logonPermission to start service using c#.

Regards,
Neil

Comment: Why do you need to check? Just try to start it and handle the error if one occurs.

Comment: I need to ask the user and inform him about the permission status, if he permits then only i need to move forward and start for him, else leave him without performing any operation.